Is Tkinter's askopenfilename safe?
I'm developing an app with Tkinter as the UI. Currently, I'm using tkinter.filedialog's askopenfilename function to let a user choose a file.
I then create a hidden file for [redacted] purposes with the same filename. As a result, I need to use subprocess which I've read can have suffer from command injection vulnerabilities if the input is not sanitized.
So far, I've done pretty minor sanitization and before I get down the weeds, I wanted to find out: does askopenfilename already pretty sanitized/safe? Or should I treat it as unsanitized as an input statement? The docs only say this:

tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(**options)


tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilenames(**options)


The above two functions
create an Open dialog and return the selected filename(s) that
correspond to existing file(s).


askopenfilename simply returns a string (file path). You only get the existing file path. Are you creating a new file using a subprocess or are you going to run a selected file using a subprocess?

subprocess can only have command injection if you use shell=True. Avoid that if you can.
